# ¿Como eliminar elementos listados del DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una duda, como puedo eliminar los elementos que he ido listando en el DOM ?? cabe destacar que no estoy guardando ningún dato en ninguna parte, ya sea LocalStorage o en un Array  Acá les comparto el código, Muchas Gracias!!

```js
let listar = document.getElementById("listar"); 
let eliminar = document.getElementById("eliminar"); 
let nombre = document.getElementById("txtNombre");
let pintar = document.getElementById("pintar");

listar.addEventListener("click", ()=>{ 
    pintar.innerHTML += "<h2>"+nombre.value+"</h2>"; 
}); 


eliminar.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
     
    
});
```

```html
    <input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" placeholder="Ingrese un Nombre"><br><br>
    <button id="listar">Listar</button>
    <h1>Nombres: </h1>
    <div id="pintar"></div>
    <input type="text" name="txtEliminar" id="txtEliminar" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre a Eliminar"><br><br>
    <button id="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Es decir ¿escribir en el input el nombre de un nodo y que entonces proceda su eliminación?

Comment: @Aprendiz Asi es compañero, eso es lo que estoy intentando resolver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const listar = document.getElementById("listar");
const eliminar = document.getElementById("eliminar");
const txtEliminar = document.getElementById("txtEliminar");
const nombre = document.getElementById("txtNombre");
const pintar = document.getElementById("pintar");
console.log(txtEliminar.value)
listar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const nodeH2 = document.createElement("H2");
  nodeH2.innerText = nombre.value.trim();
  pintar.appendChild(nodeH2);
});


eliminar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const listElements = [...pintar.childNodes]
  listElements.forEach((elementDOM) => {
    elementDOM.innerText.trim() === txtEliminar.value.trim() && pintar.removeChild(elementDOM)
  })

});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" placeholder="Ingrese un Nombre"><br><br>
<button id="listar">Listar</button>
<h1>Nombres: </h1>
<div id="pintar"></div>
<input type="text" name="txtEliminar" id="txtEliminar" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre a Eliminar"><br><br>
<button id="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
```

Inserta los nodos correctamente y luego a la hora de eliminar recorre la lista de elementos que quieres eliminar y verifica que sea igual al valor ingresado para eliminar. Te paso el ejemplo de guia.

Comment: Ohhh master, muchas gracias de verdad te pasaste, no sabes cuanto tiempo me estuve cabeceando este problema y tu en rato lo lograste, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cambie el innerText por innerHTML

```js
const listar = document.getElementById("listar");
const eliminar = document.getElementById("eliminar");
const txtEliminar = document.getElementById("txtEliminar");
const nombre = document.getElementById("txtNombre");
const pintar = document.getElementById("pintar");


listar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const nodeH2 = document.createElement("H2");
  nodeH2.innerText = nombre.value.trim();
  pintar.appendChild(nodeH2);
});


eliminar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const listElements = [...pintar.childNodes]
  console.log(listElements)
  listElements.forEach((elementDOM) => {
    elementDOM.innerHTML.trim() === txtEliminar.value.trim() && pintar.removeChild(elementDOM)
  })
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" placeholder="Ingrese un Nombre"><br><br>
    <button id="listar">Listar</button>
    <h1>Nombres: </h1>
    <div id="pintar"></div>
    <input type="text" name="txtEliminar" id="txtEliminar" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre a Eliminar"><br><br>
<button id="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
```

Comment: Lo intente de esa manera, cipiando tu codigo pero no me funciono :( sabes porque ??

Comment: te aparece algun error en la consola?

Comment: No, ninguno, tu ya lo probaste y/o ejecutaste para ver si funcionaba??

Comment: Modifique mi respuesta