# ¿Como comparar un dato de un input con un arreglo para poder así eliminar el dato del arreglo?

Tags: javascript, html, aplicación-web

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy listando todo lo que voy ingresando en un input y a la vez estos datos los voy guardando en un array(sin Base de datos ni en el LocalStorage), ahora una vez realizado el listado, quiero eliminar alguno de los datos listados, poniendo el valor que quiero eliminar en un nuevo input y al presionar el boton eliminar, que se me elimine del array y de la lista que esta en el DOM.

```js
let nombre = document.getElementById("txtNombre"); 
let listar = document.getElementById("listar"); 
let pintar = document.getElementById("pintar"); 
let btnEliminar = document.getElementById("btnEliminar"); 
let txtEliminar = document.getElementById("txtEliminar"); 
let array = []; 

const agregar = (e)=>{
    array.push(nombre.value); 
    console.log(array);  
    pintar.innerHTML+="<h3>"+nombre.value+"</h3>"
}

const borrar = ()=>{
    
}

listar.addEventListener("click", agregar); 
btnEliminar.addEventListener("click", borrar);
```

```html
    <input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" placeholder="Ingrese un nombre"><br><br>
    <button id="listar">Listar</button>
    <h1>Nombres: </h1>
    <div id="pintar"></div>
    <input type="text" name="txtEliminar" id="txtEliminar" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre a Eliminar"><br><br>
    <button id="btnEliminar">Eliminar</button>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como eliminar elementos listados del DOM?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317222/como-eliminar-elementos-listados-del-dom)

Comment: @VictorAlvarez La verdad es que no, ya que yo ahora estoy guardando los datos ingresados en un array, y en el otro no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const listar = document.getElementById("listar");
const eliminar = document.getElementById("eliminar");
const txtEliminar = document.getElementById("txtEliminar");
const nombre = document.getElementById("txtNombre");
const pintar = document.getElementById("pintar");
let listText = [];
listar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const nodeH2 = document.createElement("H2");
  nodeH2.innerText = nombre.value.trim();
  listText.push(nodeH2.innerText);
  pintar.appendChild(nodeH2);
});


eliminar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const listElements = [...pintar.childNodes]
  listElements.forEach((elementDOM) => {
    elementDOM.innerText.trim() === txtEliminar.value.trim() && pintar.removeChild(elementDOM)
  })
  listText = [...listText].filter(itemText => itemText !== txtEliminar.value.trim())
  console.log(listText);

});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" placeholder="Ingrese un Nombre"><br><br>
<button id="listar">Listar</button>
<h1>Nombres: </h1>
<div id="pintar"></div>
<input type="text" name="txtEliminar" id="txtEliminar" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre a Eliminar"><br><br>
<button id="eliminar">Eliminar</button>
```

Añade los elementos de texto al array, luego de ellos cuando elimines, filtra todos los elementos que sean diferentes al texto a eliminar.

Comment: Y como puedo filtrar todos los elementos que sean diferentes al texto para eliminar??, lo podrías realizar por favor!?

Comment: En el ejemplo filtro todos los elementos que son diferentes al texto a eliminar. `filter` me devuelve un nuevo array con todas las coincidencias. Por ese motivo cuando filtro todas las diferentes al texto a eliminar ya no existirá en dicho array, por ende el nuevo array constara de todos los elementos menos el elemento que eliminas